# compile protobuf client code on ubuntu, but include file is not found

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, include, protocol-buffers

I just installed google protocol buffer on my ubuntu1604:

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

And tried a quick test, 1 proto file, 1 cpp file to use it, try to see the encode/decode results:

```
$ cat 1.proto
package x;
message my{
required string name=1;
required int32 id=2;
optional string email=3;
}

$ cat 1.cpp
#include"1.pb.cc"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace x;
int main()
{
  my p;
  p.set_name("tom");
  p.set_id(18);
  p.set_email("aa@bb.com");
  string s;
  my.SerializeToString(&s);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it, failed to find include files:

```
protoc 1.proto --cpp_out=./
g++ 1.cpp 1.pb.cc -lprotobuf

In file included from 1.pb.cc:5:0,
             from 1.cpp:1:
1.pb.h:9:42: fatal error: google/protobuf/stubs/common.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from 1.pb.cc:5:0:
1.pb.h:9:42: fatal error: google/protobuf/stubs/common.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not install associated protobuf header and lib, which is independent from protobuf-compiler. Run:
`sudo apt install libprotobuf-dev`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This missing package is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This was also the solution for "google/protobuf/any.proto: File not found." when compiling a python protobuf on ubuntu. Commenting in case it helps others find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Linux environment, you can：

1. download directly any version from [protocol buffer github release website](https://%20https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/)
2. Unzip the package
3. Move **protoc-version-arch/include/google** to **/usr/local/include** or other similar place