# protoc with grpc_python_plugin: google/protobuf/any.proto: File not found

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm running this command:

```
protoc protobuf/file.proto --proto_path=protobuf --proto_path=protobuf --python_out=out/builtin_pb --grpc_out=out/builtin_pb --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/usr/local/bin/grpc_python_plugin
```

where file.proto has:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
```

And stuff like:

```
google.protobuf.Any arg = 3;
```

However, it has the error:

```
google/protobuf/any.proto: File not found.
bess_msg.proto: Import "google/protobuf/any.proto" was not found or had errors.
bess_msg.proto:251:3: "google.protobuf.Any" is not defined 
...
```

Are there any steps I can follow to make sure any.proto is properly installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had this error when trying to compile a protobuf to python on Ubuntu. My problem was that I had installed the compiler using `sudo apt install protobuf-compiler`, but I had not installed the resources using `sudo apt install libprotobuf-dev`.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41604412/767314) for showing me the error of my ways.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered this issue and realized that I was using protobuf 3.0. Simply upgrade the protobuf compiler to the latest version (3.6 in my case) for definitions on those types.